# Telerik RadAutoComplete Textbox only allowing to save or enter the values that exsists only in the table

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete, telerik

I have a Telerik RadAutoCompleteBox. The requirement is that " People can input something new, so that the next person that comes in can select that new value.  This should keep the responses as consistent as possible. ". So i created a table for this with some 5 entries and these are showed in the dropdownlist. Now the issue is the RadAutoCompleteBox is taking only those 5 entries and its not allowing the user to enter anything else. Can anyone help me this.

```
<div style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; border-left: solid 1px #CCCCCC;">
   <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="Category1TB1" EmptyMessage="Please type here"  AutoPostBack ="true" 
           DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Comments" InputType="Text" Width="270" DropDownWidth="150px" Delimiter=" " DataValueField="Comments">
   </telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
</div>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ems_dbConnectionString %>"
     ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT [Comments]  FROM [EMS_WORKEFFORTS_TASKS_CAT1]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

On save:

```
 Protected Sub Category1SaveBtn1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles category1SaveBtn1.Click
    Try
        Dim db As New EmsLinqClassesDataContext

        Dim updTsk = (From w In db.WorkEffortTasks _
                    Where w.TASK_ID = _taskID _
                    Select w).Single()

        Category1TB1.Focus()
        updTsk.CATEGORY1 = Category1TB1.Text
        Category1Lbl1.Text = Category1TB1.Text

        db.SubmitChanges()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New EmsException(Page.User.Identity.Name, EmsLib.GetCurrentPageName(), "Category1SaveBtn1_Click", ex)
    End Try

    Category1View1.SetActiveView(C1_ViewMode)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

BY adding 'AllowCustomEntry="true" ' it resolved my issue

```
 <div style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; border-left: solid 1px #CCCCCC;">
   <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="Category1TB1" EmptyMessage="Please type here"  AutoPostBack ="true" 
           DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Comments" InputType="Text" Width="270" DropDownWidth="150px" Delimiter=" " DataValueField="Comments" AllowCustomEntry="true>
   </telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
</div>
```